# Permalinks not working for sub-directory WordPress site

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress website in www.example.com domain.
Now I created "en" folder, and install another worpdress site to that folder.

When I set "Post name" in Permalink Settings and go to one of my pages for example www.example.com/en/about -> I get 404.

Comment: have you changed the **en** database permalinks to **http://www.example.com/en**

Comment: Have you updated your Site URL and Home URL in Settings?

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the .htaccess that you install on this folder "en"

Comment: can you please let me know what you add or change in htacces

Comment: did you change the wp-config.php file as well?

Comment: I added: 
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /en/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /en/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: No I did not add anything in wp-config.php